# ¿Como hacer un canvas que no interactua?

Tags: html

presento un problema y es el siguiente:

Tengo un canvas el cual su función es lanzar confeti por toda la web. El problema esá en que no me deja interactucar con el resto del sitio web.

Este es el código:

```
<canvas style="height:100%;width:100%;position: absolute; top: 0;z-index:1;" id="confeti"></canvas>
```

Lo que quiero es que se vea, pero que interactue de manera invisible.

Answer (score 1):

El `z-index` debe estar en `-1` para renderizar el canvas debajo de todos los demás elementos.

```js
var c = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("canvas", 10, 50);
```

```css
.canvas-demo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas-demo">
```